# How can I calculate Weighted Average on google sheets based on a condition?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, weighted-average

I wanted to find out a non zero weighted average from 2 arrays in google sheets - the weighted average/sumproduct should be calculated only when value in column A is not zero.

I cannot change or remove data - only a formula can solve this.

```
+----------+--------+
| Products | Orders |
+----------+--------+
|        5 |   1200 |
|        0 |   3497 |
|       14 |   1234 |
|       13 |    422 |
|        4 |   2444 |
|       21 |  13234 |
+----------+--------+
```

Desired Result = (5*1200 + 14*1234 + 13*422 + 4*2444 + 21*13234) / (1200 + 1234 + 422 + 2444 + 13234)

^^ Weights are Orders & orders where products = 0 (i.e. 2nd entry) will not be counted in the base

Comment: Pls mention the desired result

Comment: Hi, I have updated the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basis your desire result, you can try below formula

```
=sumproduct((A2:A)*(B2:B))/sumif(A2:A,">0",B2:B)
```

Answer (score 5):

if weights are in A column then:

```
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(B:B, A:A<>0), FILTER(A:A, A:A<>0))
```

[image: 0]